# Saving WordPress generated thumbnails in a subdirectory

Tags: uploads, media, directory, thumbnails

I.e. an uploaded image `image.jpg` is stored in `wp-content/uploads/2016`. WordPress will generate thumbnails named `image-150x150.jpg`, `image-300x300.jpg`, and `image-1024x1024.jpg` in the same directory.

Is it possible to store the additional image sizes generated in a subdirectory, such as `wp-content/uploads/2016/thumbs`?

Comment: good question, and most likely it is possible, but why not to do some research and find it out by yourself? It not like only "experts" on this site have access to the wordpress code....

Comment: It is not that I have not pursued recherche:

1. I first searched for a plugin, that solves my request. But I´ve found none yet.

2. I studied `media.php` to understand how WordPress generates thumbnails. My naive idea: adding a code snippet like `/thumbs` at the corresponding position in code. But this is not as easy as I had imagined.

3. I´ve searched the net and only found this:
[link](https://gist.github.com/tommymarshall/279d238d9341d68af65e5a458bef8b61)
But this script just moves WordPress generated thumbnails to `./thumbs/` folder afterwards. This is not, what I am looking for.

Comment: @MarkKaplun: if you have an idea how I can solve my request , I am pleased with your support. Just because I do not have any solution it was my motivation to ask this question here in the forum.

Comment: Check the core for the upload process code (evades my memory right now), and check how the files are generated. Maybe there is an appropriate filter over there. Worst case - find a hook after the upload was finished, copy the files to the directory in which you want them and update the relevant meta data for all the generated sizes

Comment: I assumed that my project is easy to implement. That does not seem as easy as thought. What struck me in the FTP-view the folder structure due to the numerous thumbnails is pretty confusing. But maybe I have to live with it…